# Reflection using Java's getDeclaredField

Tags: java, reflection

I have a Java generic method to get a field's value, using reflection:

```
private static Object getFieldValue(Object object, final String fieldName) {

    if (null == object) {
      return null;
    }

    Class<?> clazz = object.getClass();
    while (clazz != null) {
      try {
        Field field = clazz.getDeclaredField(fieldName);
        field.setAccessible(true);
        try {
          return field.get(object);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {

          e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {

          e.printStackTrace();
        }
      } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
        clazz = clazz.getSuperclass();
      }
    }
    return null;
}
```

It works fine for simple field names, for example:

```
getfieldValue (project, "title")
```

I want to get values from fields of related objects, for example:

```
getfieldValue (project, "task.title")
```

Answer (score 1):

Use apache bean util:
http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Apache-Common/UseBeanUtilstogetpropertyvaluefromobject.htm

obviously you could write your own code (split a string such as "task.title", and recursively use your getField. But it's already there in apache's code.

Comment: One more note - your code works, but you might also consider using introspection (BeanInfo), this is an alternative way to extract the fields, with minor variations (e.g. it automatically knows a boolean field might have "isXXX" instead of getXXX). It doesn't work recursively through, so it's still best to use Apache beanUtils

Answer (score 1):

The simple solution would be to write some code to split `"task.title"` into components (e.g. using `String.split(...)` ) and then chain together a sequence of `getFieldValue` calls.